# How can I fix an error from building a 3D printing slicer software for a robotic arm based on a provided code from GitHub, getting an error LNK1181?

Tags: slicing, software, printer-building, python

Not sure if the right place to ask this particular question but will try anyway. Currently trying to run a software as presented in the link here: [GitHub - zhangty019/S3_DeformFDM: S^3-Slicer: A General Slicing Framework for Multi-Axis 3D Printing](https://github.com/zhangty019/S3_DeformFDM) and without success, ergo this post.

I have been following the instructions provided in the GitHub repository to the point. The only difference in the execution has been that I am running it in VS22 instead of VS19 but this has been adjusted by the following: GKLLib/QMeshLib/ShapeLab > Right click > Properties > Configuration Properties > General > Platform Toolset > Visual Studio 2022 (v143).

A few initial errors have been presented after the initial build but that has been rectified by the following:

Specified paths of libraries and directories in the build files, specifically the ShapeLab. That has been done by the following process:

1. Solution explorer > ShapeLab > Properties > Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories > Edit > Include Directories > New Line > paste in directory path: `D:\oneAPI\mkl\2024.0\include`

and as well,

2. Solution explorer > ShapeLab > Properties > Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Library Directories > Edit > Include Directories > New Line > paste in directory path: `D:\oneAPI\mkl\2024.0\lib`

The software build process has now been brought to a halt by a single error presented below:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details

Error LNK1181 cannot open input file 'D:\oneAPI\mkl\2024.0\lib.obj' ShapeLab D:\Documents\GitHub\githubTest\S3_DeformFDM\ShapeLab\LINK 1
```

When I search in the specified file with File Explorer I find that the lib is actually a folder with other subfolders inside of it and other `.obj` files included. In contrast, there is no file by the name `lib.obj`.

When searching the web not many helpful tips or tricks have been found so not sure what is to be done to fix this particular error.

Does anyone know what could be done to fix this?

Comment: You're trying to solve a software build issue by asking on a 3D-printing site? Maybe try [SO] instead... Or, maybe just posting an issue on the GitHub repository.

Comment: We often have questions about building 3D printer firmware (i.e. Marlin, or whatever), and we can help. However, (and maybe I am wrong) this seems to be a question not about a common, or commercial, 3D printer, nor about a printer's firmware, but rather a piece of third-party robotics software. I have read the question a few times, over the past few days, and I can't really understand the issue. Is it really a build issue with the software from a Github repository? If so, then raise an issue on Github, so that the author of the software can see the issue and hopefully address the problem.

Comment: Otherwise, StackOverflow or [Robotics.SE](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) may be the place to ask. If it really is 3D printing related, then please clarify the issue, and hopefully someone will have an answer. Hi and welcome, BTW :-)